# How do I place type bodies and specs in the same document?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm creating several types with bodies and specs in Oracle and would like them in the same document.  They're auto-generated into a single file and I would prefer not to have to create a separate document for each type body and spec.

Is there a separation command like SQL Server's 'GO' or some other method I can use to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`/` (slash)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm) to separate and submit the create statements, assuming you're running the script from SQL*Plus, SQL Developer or something similar:

```
create or replace type t42 as object
(
  data varchar2(20),
  member function get_data return varchar2
);
/

create or replace type body t42 as 
  member function get_data return varchar2 is
  begin
    return data;
  end get_data;
end;
/
```